# How to monkey patch an instance method of an external library that uses other instance methods internally?

Tags: python, python-decorators, monkeypatching

I need to patch a logic in an instance method of a library I am using.
Sample code for brevity. The `process` method is using the `connect` method of the `Client` library as is but I want to modify it to use a different logic instead of parsing_logic_1. What is the best approach to do this? How do I access the class variables like url if I add a new `_patched_connect`  method in the `Usage` class?

```py
class Client:
    def __init__(self, url)
        self.url = url
    def connect (self):
        if self.url == 'a':
         self._parsing_logic_1()
        if self.url == 'b':
         self._parsing_logic_2()
         else:
            pass
    def _parsing_logic_1(self):
        pass
    def _parsing_logic_2(self):
        pass
    def send(self):
        pass

# ----separate file --------

 class Usage:
    def __init__(self, client: Client):
        self.client = client
    
    def process(input):
        self.client.connect() # the connect method should use a different parsing logic for one case
        self.client.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your class and just replace the method with a modified method.
In python you can replace a method dynamically as you wish.

Example:

```py
from x.y.z import Client

def mynewconnect(self):
    # your code here
    self.url = "..."
    pass
Client.connect = mynewconnect
```

Comment: what is the `self` in mynewconnect() method? is it the instance of that client class? do i not need to pass that explicitly?

Comment: @sparkstar Whenever you call an instance's method, that instance is automatically passed as the first argument, without you doing anything. Here's some more info: https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why

Comment: `self` is only a convention, not a keyword: you can use any name you want in your method. You only have to know, as you and @CrazyChucky wrote, that first argument received inside a method is the instance of the client class.